# Is there a stable Emacs automated packaging system?

Tags: emacs

I'm using Gnu Emacs on OSX, Windows, and Linux. Is there some command which can download and install packages (or .el files) automatically? I've seen there are some work-in-progress projects on the internet (after googling) but I was wondering if I was missing some awesome package manager out there that just works.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, the Emacs development mailing list has a long discussion regarding integrating a package manager [package.el](http://tromey.com/elpa/install.html) into the next major release of Emacs: [Integrating package.el](http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-devel/2010-01/threads.html#00112).  It automatically downloads and installs packages from the [ELPA (Emacs Lisp Package Archive](http://tromey.com/elpa/index.html).  Read the [installation page](http://tromey.com/elpa/install.html) to obtain the latest.

Answer (score 3):

You could also try [el-get](https://github.com/dimitri/el-get). I handles installation of packages from ELPA, git, and apt-get among others.